# Unable to connect with php and my sql

Tags: php, mysql

when i try the `php` script with postman i get this error:`Unable to connect`

the credential are correct.

This is my code:

dbDetails.php

```
<?php
 define('DB_HOST','localhost');
 define('DB_USER','root');
 define('DB_PASSWORD','root');
 define('DB_DATABASE','prova');

 $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

UPLOAD.php:

```
<?php
     require_once 'dbDetails.php';

//response array
$response = array();


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['url']) and isset($_POST['name'])){

             $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');

        //getting name from the request
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        try{
             $sql = "INSERT INTO `pdfs` (`id`, `url`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$url', '$name');";

                if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

                //filling response array with values
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['url'] = $url;
                $response['name'] = $name;
            }
            //if some error occurred
        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
        } 
        //closing the connection
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Please choose a file';
    }

    //displaying the response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Someone can help me?

THANKS!

Comment: check your creds for root

Comment: Why are you using $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...'); in your upload php while you have already used it in dbDetails.php

Comment: 1.check for clear error:- `$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_connect_error());` 2. no  need of `$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect...');` second time in your code when you already included your db connection file

Comment: Where did DB_NAME come from? And DB_USERNAME?

Comment: You are also attempting to connect twice, once in dbDetails and once in upload.

Comment: @SushankPokharel THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

pls use as below:-

`$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);`

Comment: I create a class for connection and put this in the `__construct()` and then use this connection into `$this->connection` and use my connection class wherever I need...it works for me.